# MySQL union returns mixed columns

Tags: mysql, union

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

I have this script:

```
(select * from (select * from a where a_in > 2) t1 LEFT join b using (sid)) 
union 
(select * from a right join (select * from b where b_in > 2) t2 using (sid));
```

the tables are:

```
a
sid name    a_in
1   hello   2
2   me      3
3   hhh     3

b
id sid b_in
1   1   3
2   2   3
3   3   2

CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `sid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_in` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_in` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The result, for some reason is mixed:

```
sid name    a_in    id      b_in
2   me      3       2       3
3   hhh     3       3       2
1   1       3       hello   2
2   2       3       me      3
```

the expected result should have been:

```
sid name    a_in    id      b_in
2   me      3       2       3
3   hhh     3       3       2
1   hello   2       1       3
```

So, the question is - why the columns are mixed??

Comment: Please post desired resultset. Your definition of "mixed" is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
(select t1.*,b.* from (select * from a where a_in > 2) t1 LEFT join b using (sid)) 
union 
(select a.*,t2.* from a right join (select * from b where b_in > 2) t2 using (sid))
```

Comment: That should work better, except for the dup `sid` column.  (`USING(sid)` avoids making 2 columns.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for! Didn't want to write all fields implicitly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, now I realise that 'Union' don't bother searching and matching the fields from the different queries, and instead - expects the order of the field list to be the same as the first query. 
And because I didn't provide a field list implicitly (I used *) - it took some "random" order for each query, and the orders didn't match.

So, the first order that was taken automatically was 
sid, name, a_in, id, b_in.
while the second query order (that was also taken automatically) was:
sid, id, a_in, name, b_in.